# Htaccess html file from being indexed

Tags: .htaccess

Hey we are trying to prevent just one file from being indexed by google.  "preview.html"

How can we set this up to allow everything else but deny this one html file?

Comment: Hummn.  Not sure that this is a `.htaccess` tag, as this isn't the way that I'd do this.  Try [WP:robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```